# sigma-algebra of first category sets and their complements

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory, baire-category

Let $(X,d)$ a *complete* metric space and set
$$
\mathcal{M} = \{B \subset X : \quad \text{$B$ is of first category $\,$ or $\,$ $B^c=X \backslash B$ is of first category}\}
$$
(i) $\quad$ Prove that $\mathcal{M}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.
(ii) $\quad$Does $\mathcal{M}$ contain the Borel $\sigma$-algebra?

My difficulty is proving the stability w.r.t. countable intersection/union - i.e. if $A,B^c$ are first category sets, then $A \cup B \in \mathcal{M}$.
About point (ii) I still have no ideas.

I really appreciate any help :)

Comment: It’s immediate from the definition that any subset of a first category set is first category, as is any countable union of first category sets.

Comment: for (ii).  Do you know a Borel set $E$ such that neither $E$ nor $E^c$ is of first category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all $A_n$ are first category, so is $\bigcup_n A_n$. If one of them is of the second type, i.e. $A^\complement_{n_0}$ is first category, then $(\bigcup_n A_n)^\complement = \bigcap A_n^\complement \subseteq A_{n_0}^\complement$ is also of first category, so in either case $\bigcup_n A_n \in \mathcal{M}$.

Closedness under complemention is built in and trivial, as is the fact that $X \in \mathcal{M}$ and $\emptyset \in \mathcal{M}$. So being a $\sigma$-algebra is easy.

In $\Bbb R$ you can come up with a Borel set $E$ such that neither $E$ not $E^\complement$ is first category. So (ii)'s answer is *not always*. More trivial example: in $X=\Bbb Z$ no non-empty subsets are first category, so $\mathcal{M}=\{\emptyset,X\}$ there.